# how to get separate date and time feild form db datetimefield

Tags: django

```
views.py

            event_full_datetime =datetime(Editrow.datetime_reading.year,Editrow.datetime_reading.month,Editrow.datetime_reading.day, Editrow.datetime_reading.hour, 
            Editrow.datetime_reading.minute,  Editrow.datetime_reading.second)
            date=event_full_datetime.year ,event_full_datetime.month,event_full_datetime.day
            time=event_full_datetime.hour,event_full_datetime.minute

            print time
            print date


            form = KEBReading_form()
            form.Date=date
            form.Time=time
            form = KEBReading_form(instance=Editrow)
```

in the databse i have a datetimefield but in my forms i have separate date and time field. i want to populate the date and time field with values when i click on Edit. and that instance should have all the values

i gave it as

```
 form = KEBReading_form(instance=Editrow)
            print "htjrit"

            print instance.datetime_reading.date()

            form = KEBReading_form(initial={'Date': instance.datetime_reading.date(),
                     'Time': instance.datetime_reading.time()
                    }
            )
 return render_to_response('keb.html',{'KEBReading_form':form,'MonthForm':monthform,'q2':q2,},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should [specify that the form field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#specifying-widgets) should use [SplitDateTimeWidget](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#splitdatetimewidget).

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the separate date and time values for a form through `initial` parameter.

So if your model has *somedatetime* field and form has `somedate` and `sometime` fields, you can instantiate form as

```
myform = MyForm(initial={'somedate': instance.somedatetime.day(),
                         'sometime': instance.somedatetime.time()
                        }
                )
```

Comment: @prithu, good, but make sure you combine it properly again when you want to save the model instance.